# Egrep expression: how to unescape single quotes when reading from file?

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I need to use `egrep` to obtain an entry in an index file.

In order to find the entry, I use the following command:

```
egrep "^$var_name" index
```

`$var_name` is the variable read from a var list file:

```
while read var_name; do
    egrep "^$var_name" index
done < list
```

One of the possible keys comes usually in this format:

```
$ERROR['SOME_VAR']
```

My index file is in the form:

```
$ERROR['SOME_VAR'] --> n
```

Where `n` is the line where the variable is found.

The problem is that `$var_name` is automatically escaped when read. When I enable the debug mode, I get the following command being executed:

```
+ egrep '^$ERRORS['\''SELECT_COUNTRY'\'']' index
```

The command above doesn't work, because `egrep` will try to interpret the pattern.

If I don't use the extended version, using `grep` or `fgrep`, the command will work only if I remove the `^` anchor:

```
grep -F "$var_name" index # this actually works
```

The problem is that I **need** to ensure that the match is made at the beginning of the line.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`set -x` shows the command being executed *in shell notation*.

The backslashes you see do **not** become part of the argument, they're just printed by `set -x` to show the executed command in a copypastable format.

Your problem is not too much escaping, but too little: `$` in regex means "end of line", so `^$ERROR` will never match anything. Similarly, `[` `]` is a character range, and will not match literal square brackets.

The correct regex to match your pattern would be `^\$ERROR\['SOME VAR']`, equivalent to the shell argument in `egrep "^\\\$ERROR\['SOME_VAR']"`.

Your options to fix this are:

1. If you expect to be able to use regex in your input file, you need to include regex escapes like above, so that your patterns are valid.
2. If you expect to be able to use arbitrary, literal strings, use a tool that can match flexibly and literally. This requires jumping through some hoops, since UNIX tools for legacy reasons are very sloppy.

Here's one with awk:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  export line
  gawk 'BEGIN{var=ENVIRON["line"];} substr($0, 0, length(var)) == var' index
done < list
```

It passes the string in through the environment (because `-v` is sloppy) and then matches literally against the string from the start of the input.

Here's an example invocation:

```
$ cat script
while IFS= read -r line
do
  export line
  gawk 'BEGIN{var=ENVIRON["line"];} substr($0, 0, length(var)) == var' index
done < list

$ cat list
$ERRORS['SOME_VAR']
\E and \Q
'"'%@#%*'

$ cat index
hello world
$ERRORS['SOME_VAR'] = 'foo';
\E and \Q are valid strings
'"'%@#%*' too
etc

$ bash script
$ERRORS['SOME_VAR'] = 'foo';
\E and \Q are valid strings
'"'%@#%*' too
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf "%q"`:

```
while read -r var_name; do
    egrep "^$(printf "%q\n" "$var_name")" index
done < list
```

**Update:** You can also do:

```
while read -r var_name; do
    egrep "^\Q$var_name\E" index
done < list
```

Here `\Q` and `\E` are used to make string in between a literal string removing all special meaning of regex symbols.

Comment: This will prevent backslashes from being used as escape character READING the file. There are no backslashes in the file. I ran the command with this option, but nothing has changed. The output of the debug is still the same...

Comment: `printf %q` escapes for shells, not for regex.

Comment: Agreed but it worked for the sample data provided in question.

Comment: Debug shows this: `+ egrep '^\$ERRORS\[\'\''SELECT_COUNTRY\'\''\]'`... It doesn't work either...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos: Can you tell me output of: `var_name='$ERROR['SOME_VAR']'; egrep "$(printf "%q\n" "$var_name")" <<< '$ERROR['SOME_VAR'] --> 10'` I am getting `$ERROR[SOME_VAR] --> 10`

Comment: It is tested and working code. Instead of `egrep` you can also also use `grep -P`